# How to build SCOM 2012 management pack using msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, scom

I have a Visual Studio project which I'm building with Visual Studio and everything works fine. When I'm trying to build it using `msbuild.exe /t:Build F:\BuildSource\SCOMManagementPacks\2012\Packs.sln` I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VSAC\Microsoft.SystemCenter.OperationsManager.targets(223,5): error MSB4018: T
he "VerifyManagementPackFragment" task failed unexpectedly.\r [F:\BuildSource\SCOMManagementPacks\2012\Zabbix.Linux.
Library\Zabbix.Linux.Library.mpproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VSAC\Microsoft.SystemCenter.OperationsManager.targets(223,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'F:\BuildSource\SCOMManagementPacks\2012\Zabbix.Linux.Library\Fr
agmentSchemaOM20.xsd'.\r [F:\BuildSource\SCOMManagementPacks\2012\Zabbix.Linux.Library\Zabbix.Linux.Library.mppro
j]
```

There's no such file on my original machine where I was building the solution using Visual Studio and everything's building fine.
How can I fix this?

Comment: After adding those files from VSAE to project folder I'm getting this error: `01.MPName.mpx(2729,20): error : Undefined complexType 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10:sectionsType' is used
as a base for complex type restriction` though in Visual Studio projects builds without any errors.

Comment: "Clean" in Visual Studio helped and now everything works.